# Laravel 5.5 Multi Currency app best practices

Tags: php, laravel, currency

There are lot of packages for currencies but I didn't find anything on the multi-currency app.

Ideally, the multicurrency package should convert and display currencies according to the currency stored in the locale. The base currency is USD.

So calling `{{currency(299)}}` should convert 299 into the currency stored in session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the attribute on the model and override the return value:

```
public function getPriceAttribute($val)
{
    $locale = config('app.locale');

    return currency($val, 'USD',  $locale);
}
```

Assuming you have a `price` column defined on your model that is stored in the `USD` format.

The `currency` function is supplied by a package [like this one](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-currency).

If you need a more precise and accurate conversion calcuator, you're going to want to use something like http://fixer.io/ - and there's a [beautiful package that integrates this](https://github.com/florianv/swap) which I've found very useful.